# Use child data inside parent function using node js

Tags: node.js, async-await, promise, nodes

I want to return a value and store it in a variable. I don't know this can be possible or not but I tried to so

```js
let demo = await Promise.all(
                    Shop.findAll({
                      where: {
                        product_id: child.id,
                      },
                      attributes: ["id", "address"],
                    })
                      .then((adds) => {
                        adds.map(async function (add) {
                          let path = add.address;
                          return path;
                        });
                      })
                      .catch(function (err) {
                        reject(err);
                      })
                  );
                  console.log(demo);
```

All I am getting is `demo = []`

- As my expected ouput from demo is

```
New York
London
Mumbai
Sydney
```

- And in reality I am getting `demo= []`

What I am trying to do is that I need the address of the shop in the parent function as Shop is my child function so my actual code looks like this

```js
Owner.findAll({
            raw: true,
            where: {
              id: owner.id,
            },
            attributes: ["id", "name", "address"],
          })
            .then(async (children) => {

              await Promise.all(
                children.map(async function (child) {
                 let ownerName = child.name;
                 
                  let demo = await Promise.all(
                    Shop.findAll({
                      where: {
                        product_id: child.id,
                      },
                      attributes: ["id", "address"],
                    })
                      .then((adds) => {
                        adds.map(async function (add) {
                          let path = add.address;
                          return path;
                        });
                      })
                      .catch(function (err) {
                        reject(err);
                      })
                  );
                 // I want to use demo in getStatus function
                  await getStatus(ownerName,demo);
                })
              );
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
              reject(err);
            });
```

I want to use shop data in my owner data

Comment: `.catch(function (err) { reject(err); })` reminds me of the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)?

Comment: Yes @Bergi its a promise constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a set of errors in the script:

- missing `return`: `Promise.all` is not receiving any promise array
- there are unnecessary `async/await` wrapping that adds overhead to the code
- there is an `async` function that is sync actually `let path = add.address;`
- Mixing `async/await` with `then/catch` chaining makes the code hard to read and understand
- `catch` and `reject` multiple times

You can write it like this:

```js
let demo = await Shop.findAll({
  where: { product_id: child.id, },
  attributes: ["id", "address"],
})
  .then(adds => {
    return adds.map(toPath);
  })

function toPath(item) {
  let path = item.address;
  return path;
}
```

Or the second one:

```js
return Owner.findAll({
  raw: true,
  where: {
    id: owner.id
  },
  attributes: ['id', 'name', 'address']
})
  .then((children) => {
    return Promise.all(children.map(processChild))
  })

async function processChild (child) {
  const ownerName = child.name

  const adds = await Shop.findAll({
    where: { product_id: child.id },
    attributes: ['id', 'address']
  })
  const demo = adds.map(add => add.address)

  const status = await getStatus(ownerName, demo)
  // manage the `status` or just `return getStatus(ownerName, demo)`
  return status
}
```

Notice about the:

```
.catch(function (err) {
  reject(err);
})
```

in the `Shop.findAll` code, could lead to multiple reject calls, which leads to a memory leak.
Doing like the snippet I posted, chain all the promises and let you set only one `catch`.

Since there is a `reject` function, I assume you are wrapping your code in a promise:

```js
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  Owner.findAll({...})
    .then(...)
    .catch(function (err) {
      reject(err);
    })
})
```

This is unnecessary because you need just to return the promise returned by `Owner.findAll`, this code is the same:

```js
return Owner.findAll({...})
    .then(...)
```